# How to get the start date in analytics reporting api?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

I am currently using Google Analytics Reporting API in my application. It has only one method, which is accessible on the next url - https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet.
Using this method, I should specify the time range to get data from that period.

Example of request body:

```
{
"reportRequests": [
    {
        "metrics": [
            {
                "expression": "ga:users"
            }
        ]
        "dateRanges": [
            {
                "startDate": "2017-01-01",
                "endDate": "2017-12-01"
            }
        ],
        "viewId": "1111111"
    }
]
}
```

Is there any way to know the date when analytics started? Any suggestions?

Comment: May be you should add `ga:date` dimension in your request!

Comment: Thank you for advice, that could help hmm.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, finally the next approach helped.
You can make a request adding "ga:sessions" in metrics and "ga:date" in dimensions. Start date should be November 14, 2005. If you make this request, you will get a list of session count, grouped by dates. First date when sessions began would be specified in the first entry of the response.
Thank you guys for your help!

Edit:

Some example.

Json request body:

```
{
"reportRequests": [
    {
        "metrics": [
            {
                "expression": "ga:sessions"
            }
        ],
        "dimensions": [
            {
                "name": "ga:date"
            }
        ],
        "dateRanges": [
            {
                "startDate": "2005-11-14",
                "endDate": "2021-03-17"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Json response body:

```
"data": {
            "rows": [
                {
                    "dimensions": [
                        "20120711"
                    ],
                    "metrics": [
                        {
                            "values": [
                                "10"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

This way we can see the first date when analytics started. Maybe this will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

## [dateRanges[] object(DateRange)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet)

> Date ranges in the request. The request can have a maximum of 2 date ranges. The response will contain a set of metric values for each combination of the dimensions for each date range in the request. So, if there are two date ranges, there will be two set of metric values, one for the original date range and one for the second date range. The reportRequest.dateRanges field should not be specified for cohorts or Lifetime value requests. If a date range is not provided, the default date range is (startDate: current date - 7 days, endDate: current date - 1 day). Every ReportRequest within a batchGet method must contain the same dateRanges definition.

Your data will be returned for the dates you specify in your report.  In your example above you will only see data for January 1st, 2017.

## google analysic state date.

The only way I know of to find the start date for a google analytics account is to start by requesting data from November 14, 2005 and keep going until you start getting results that will be your start date.

November 14, 2005 was the public release date of google analytics.

## account summaries

Even the [account summaries](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries#resource) endpoints do not contain any date information as to when an account was created.

Comment: Yes, I undestand how that json "startDate" field works, but I want to know the exact start date.
For example, if the site was started in 2018, January 1, but users started to visit it from February 1, how to know that there were no users in that month?
That's the problem.
In my case I would like to impliment something like paging by dates, but to know the actual start date is really important.

Comment: You dont.   The only start date you are going to be able to find will be the first date it was recoreded.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way using the reporting API and the Node.js client library.

```js
import { google } from "googleapis";
const analytics = google.analytics("v3");

const first = await analytics.data.ga.get({
    auth: client, // this is the client that has the refresh token
    ids: "ga:xxx",
    "start-date": "2005-11-14", // The first date of Google Analytics
    "end-date": "today",
    filters: "ga:sessions>0", // Get the first date with recorded sessions.
    metrics: "ga:sessions",
    dimensions: "ga:date",
    "max-results": 1,
});

console.log(first.data?.rows);
```

The output would be something like this:

```json
[ [ '20180505', '4' ] ]
```

Where the first entry in the array is the date in `YYYYMMDD` format and the second one is the number of sessions.

Answer (score -1):

To add to what you've mentioned as your solution above, when I'm creating report requests, I think about how I'd want to see the data in Google Analytics and work from there.

Adding a dimension in the report request is the same as adding a secondary dimension in any of the reports like All Pages, Channels, Geo, Technology, etc. The list goes on and on.

That's something that's always helped me through the years, so just passing along a friendly suggestion. More than happy to assist if you have any other questions, I've been using this API for about two years now. Cheers!